# i have proxy error while installing igraph in anaconda in windows 10,python 3.7

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

i tried(spyder,windows 10,python 3.7) : "conda install -c marufr python-igraph"

this happened:

Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ProxyError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required')))"))

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for setting up the .condarc config file and adding proxy server entries.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621792/5745815